# how to send email after registration in java spring mvc

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring mvc , hibernate . i have one registration form where when the user fills the form and data enters in dtabase , i want to send email to user about their username an and login details.

SO how can i send email in spring

Comment: the same way you send it without spring. Search around - there are plenty of answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to confirm email addrees in spring MVC web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273547/how-to-confirm-email-addrees-in-spring-mvc-web-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from any java program, desktop or web

```
    Authenticator auth = new MailAuthenticator();
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, false));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(rcpt, false));
    msg.setContent(msgContent, "text/html");
    Transport.send(msg);
```

properties is a java.util.Properties object, whose content are loaded from a properties file. Here is the file

```
mail.from=s@t.com
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.user=user@gmail.com
mail.pass=mygmailpassword
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.auth=true
```

Comment: thanks sbuddy u mean my filename should be email.properties but where should i put in my project and in which directory. also if my file name is email.properties , where i ur code i need to chnage that name . i mean in getInstance(email.properties,auth) . Am i right

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
```

E.G. [HERE](http://book.javanb.com/Professional-Java-Development-with-the-Spring-Framework/BBL0078.html)

Comment: Link doesn't open. Post is useless.