# How to confirm email addrees in spring MVC web application

Tags: java, hibernate, email, spring-mvc

I am registering user with email address . but i want to send the user a confirmation link where if they click then their email address gets confirmed

```
I am using java spring MVC hibernate mysql
```

Comment: Are you asking how to validate the email address the user entered or are you asking how to email the link ?

Comment: i have written in the question about email link

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Among other tools you can use "java mail" package to send emails direclty from your application. Here's the link to API docs [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

So the scenario could be like the following:

- User account is created. It's in unconfirmed state now;
- You generate a unique confirmation ID to your applicaiton. The easiest way is to use java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(). [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is a random globally unique value.;
- You store the ID (e.g. 0123)+account to the database for future use;
- Send the URL+ID (http://yourapp.com/confirm?id=0123) as an email using javamail to the user;
- Do not show the ID in browser now;
- The user checks inbox and see your letter;
- The user clicks the link and request is sent to your site confirmaion servlet;
- Confirmation servlet will search for the account associated with the specified confirmation id;
- Confirmaion servlet set account to "confirmed state" as obvously the user has access to the specified mail box

Comment: How can i generate the ID because user can chnage that manually as well and i don't want to accidently interfere with other users ID

Comment: The easiest way is to use java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Mail Api to create a e-mail with confirmation. Also, you need to generate unique id to confirm the user - this info can be stored in db. After the moment user clicks on your confirmation link you should set user in 'Confirmed' state.